# Django How to present user values on built-in EditProfileForm

Tags: django, database, django-forms, widget, form-fields

My form is like in the photo. I want to show user's data like name, last name , phone number ... 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A695P.jpg

in my forms.py, I edit the EditProfileForm as CustomEditProfileForm . I am trying to give user's data in value part ('value': User.Accounts.name). I don't know how to pull the data from accounts model.

```
class CustomEditProfileForm(EditProfileForm): 
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','value':User.Accounts.name}))
    middlename = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value':'username'}))
    lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value':'username'}))
    highschool = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value':'highschool'}))
    college = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value':'college'}))
    citystate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value':'citystate'}))
```

Comment: You do that in the view, by passing the profile as the instance parameter to the form.

Comment: How i can pass the profile ?  my instance parameter is like this CustomEditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user,initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name})

Comment: `CustomEditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)`. You don't need `initial`.

Comment: Are you sure about profile ? Because my users' profile datas are in Accounts model. i passed Accounts in instance and tried to pull the data on forms.py  as """name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','value':Accounts.name}))  """  and when i run the website program i get a result as "<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03964D30>"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data(CustomEditProfileForm), you use to `view.py`

and you can control data in validate function.

```
def customeditprofile_view(request):
    form = CustomEditProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        pass
```

or

```
def customeditprofile_view(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    middlename = request.POST.get('middlename')
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I did by passing "profile model name" in instance .

i  dont need built-in UserChangeForm . I had a profileform for profile . so i passed that form name in code and i passed in instance, model name "accounts" . Then i can see the values on edit page .

Thanks Daniel, views.py codes is in image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZcRg.jpg)